# Image alignment within div using CSS

Tags: css, image, alignment

I have a following problem.

I have a row of 290px x 160px squares which suppose to display images withing a div.

```
<div class="33percentWidth">
<img src="./img1" class="???" />
</div>

<div class="33percentWidth">
<img src="./img2" class="???" />
</div>

<div class="33percentWidth">
<img src="./img3" class="???" />
</div>
```

Problem is that if the image is bigger (more than 290px x 190px; this enlarges height or width.

Question: How can I define my img class so the images will be centered (and scaled) to fit 290x190 square, and to me sure that with of a "column" will persist?

Comment: `max-width` and `max-height` should work..

Comment: Your last statement is not clear:"to me sure that with of a "column" will persist?"

Comment: Basically lets say that I have a temp placeholder for each screenshot displayed in the diff - its size is exactly 290px x 160px. So the images displayed thay way are nice "grid". So looks consistent. Hwever if I do use another image  ( which is bigger) the size of row / column may change. If I use max-width, max-height the images within are streteched to mach the 290x160.

Comment: Please include the CSS you have so far for `33percentwidth`

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS

```
.classname{
  max-width :290px;
  max-height:190px;
  align-content: center;
}
```

Comment: there is no float:center

Answer (score 0):

If you give width to img tag then it will automatically fit to your column.

```
<style>
 .imgclass{
 height:160px;
 width:290px; 
 }
 .divclass{
  text-align:center; 
 }
 </style>
 <div class="divclass">
  <img src="./img1" class="imgclass" />
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's best to let the image sort it's own aspect ratio within the div..

So for sizing I would:

```
.class { max-width: 100%; height: auto}
```

And to center an image you can use either:

```
.parent { text-align: center}
```

Or

```
Img {display: block; margin: 0 auto;}
```

But the last method is only useful is the img is smaller than the parent

Answer (score 0):

Size the `div` and `max-width` the `img`

```css
.percentWidth {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 260px;
  height: 190px;
  line-height: 190px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
.percentWidth>img {
  max-width: 260px;
  max-height: 190px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="percentWidth">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/260x190&text=same" />
</div>

<div class="percentWidth">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100&text=smaller" />
</div>

<div class="percentWidth">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/280x200&text=bigger" />
</div>
```